# Can anyone identify this Chinese candy?

Tags: candy, chinese-cuisine, food-identification

We just grabbed our customary mint on our way out of the Asian Bistro by our house but when we opened it, it wasn't a mint and the wrapper was almost all in Chinese (I think).  It was an Asian bistro, but most of the food was Chinese, so I'm guessing that it's Chinese.

So the candy was green and definitely fruit flavored, but didn't taste like anything discernable. The fruit on the picture kind of looks like a pear, but not really any of our western pears. (Sorry for the fuzzy image, my phone would not focus and the wrapper was so small, so small)

[image]

Comment: Hold the camera back from the wrapper farther and it will probably focus just fine.

Comment: I think if you'd gotten a clear picture, Google's search by image would probably have found it for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is Classic Series Guava Candy made by HongYuan. You can buy a 14oz bag on Amazon, [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J0N1CK).

Comment: Awesome! Thx! I wouldn't have thought of guava...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.21food.com/products/guava-fruit-flavor-hard-candy-162402.html

Guava candy that was given free at a Chinese Restaurant

Answer (score -1):

It is called Guava flavored Chinese candy.